# Rails: ReferenceError: google is not defined

Tags: google-maps-api-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am getting "ReferenceError: google is not defined" error on my application.js

This is what my js contains:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var options = {
types: [],
componentRestrictions: {country: 'in'}
};
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
});
```

Not getting why this error is coming. My search function is working properly but web console giving this error.

Can anybody tell solution on this?

Comment: Uh, are you loading in the Google maps API JS file?  You might need to post more code, because it's not present in what you've posted so far

Comment: @duncan This is what i am posting: <%= text_field_tag 'search', nil, :id=>"searchTextField", :class => "homecatg" %>
                                          <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>

Comment: Make sure the <script> tag occurs in the head of your page so it can be loaded before your document.ready executes I'd say.

Answer (score 1):

As [duncan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/492335/duncan) said the problem can be with include tag.

I was including GoogleMaps API at top of show page (so out of HEAD tag) like that

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=#{ENV['GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY']}" %>
```

To get rid of this

> ReferenceError: google is not defined

I changed the place where I included API from top of show page to `layouts/application.html.erb`  into head tag.

```
<head>
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=#{ENV['GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY']}" %> 
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, change the order:
first

```
<script src="maps.googleapis.com/maps/api.... >
```

then

```
 <%= text_field_tag 'search', nil, :id=>"searchTextField", :class => "homecatg" %>
```

In that case the google will be defined before used.